# POST: sending a post request in a url itself

Tags: json, http, url, post

I have been given a url .. `www.abc.com/details` and asked to send my name and phone number on this url using `POST`. They have told me to set the content-type as application/json and the body as valid JSON with the following keys:

```
name: name of the user
phone number: phone number of the user
```

Now i have no clue how to send this request! Will it be something like:

```
http://www.abc.com/details?method=post&name=john&phonenumber=445566
```

or do i have to use `java` to send the same?

Please help

Comment: From where do you have to send this request? An application, a webpage? In what language?

Comment: Which programming you are trying to implemented ?

Comment: that is the point .. they have just told that i'll be getting a response of 200 code if success from the server. they haven't told anything else .. can i simply write a url on the browser and submit the same? or do i have to use  a programming language?

Comment: Ideally, u'll have to use html, and jquery coupled with an AJAX request onto a PHP file that sends the data using POST. In the PHP file, you can use CURL request to POST onto your url and retrieve a response.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Based on what you provided, it is pretty simple for what you need to do and you even have a number of ways to go about doing it. You'll need something that'll let you post a body with your request. Almost any programming language can do this as well as command line tools like cURL.

Once you have your tool decided, you'll need to create your JSON body and submit it to the server.

An example using cURL would be (all in one line, minus the `\` at the end of the first line):

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
     -d '{"name":"your name","phonenumber":"111-111"}' http://www.example.com/details
```

The above command will create a request that should look like the following:

```
POST /details HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 44

{"name":"your name","phonenumber":"111-111"}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the usage of curl. It helps programmers unfamiliar with REST endpoints see the bare bone mechanisms of how to make one using just a terminal.

Answer (score 8):

You can post data to a url with JavaScript & Jquery something like that:

```
$.post("www.abc.com/details", {
    json_string: JSON.stringify({name:"John", phone number:"+410000000"})
});
```

Comment: In my case $.post("details", {name: "John, phone: "555-555-5555"}); worked like a charm. Tip: do it in browser console while visiting www.abc.com

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to send POST parameters in the URL in a straightforward manner. POST request in itself means sending information in the body.

I found a fairly simple way to do this. Use Postman by Google, which allows you to specify the content-type (a header field) as application/json and then provide name-value pairs as parameters.

You can find clear directions at [2020-09-04: broken link - see comment] `http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/player-management/guides/postman.html`

Just use your URL in the place of theirs.

Comment: Link is now broken: Legacy app at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop but you probably want: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabbed-postman-rest-clien/coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff  [caveat emptor: I have not verified either app]

Comment: What if you send all the arguments in the URL, like with a GET request?

Answer (score 2):

You can use postman.

Where select Post as method.
and In Request Body send JSON Object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending a request through url from browser(like consuming webservice) without using html pages by default it will be GET because GET has/needs no body. if you want to make url as POST you need html/jsp pages and you have to mention in form tag as "method=post" beacause post will have body and data will be transferred in that body for security reasons. So you need a medium (like html page) to make a POST request. You cannot make an URL as POST manually unless you specify it as POST through some medium. For example in URL (http://example.com/details?name=john&phonenumber=445566)you have attached data(name, phone number) so server will identify it as a GET data because server is receiving data is through URL but not inside a request body

Answer (score 1):

In windows this command does not work for me..I have tried the following command and **it works**..using this command I created session in couchdb sync gate way for the specific user...

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{ \"name\": \"abc\",\"password\": \"abc123\" }" http://localhost:4984/todo/_session
```

Answer (score -4):

In Java you can use `GET` which shows requested data on URL.But `POST` method cannot , because `POST` has body but `GET` donot have body.

Comment: You _can_ POST to an URL that has GET parameters (the `query`), and a GET [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) have a body. Anyway this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster maybe in RESTFUL web service GET can have body,i donot know.But, I am following the book HEAD FIRST - JSP and Servlet,from O'reilly .As per that book, my above statements in answer is correct.It may not the appropriate answer for the posted question.You can see the page no-110 in that book.GET has no body. where POST has message body and this is the key point that POST handle more data and take more parameter than GET.

Comment: But OP is not asking on advice whether to use POST or GET, the question is _how to make a POST request_.