# How to run Flask post requests in a browser?

Tags: http, flask, python-requests

http server:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    result = {'sum': request.json['a'] + request.json['b'], 'product': request.json['a'] + request.json['b']}
    return jsonify(result)
```

Client:

```
import requests

json_data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/add", json=json_data)

print(r.text)
```

How to run similar request from a browser? For example

```
http://localhost:5000/segment?text=this is a test
```

In the JSON post request, how to create the correct URL to send the parameter json_data to the server? I tried this but didn't work:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/add?json_data={'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Probably copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229852/post-sending-a-post-request-in-a-url-itself

Comment: @nd2003, how to send this POST request in a browser, i.e. Chrome?